# ffmpeg volume not work in complex filter

Tags: ffmpeg

"volume" filter does not work in complex filter. The volume is not affected in the converted audio.

env: Mac OS 10.12.6

```
ffmpeg -i /path/bg.mp3 -y -filter_complex [0:0]volume=0[output] -map 
[output] -acodec libmp3lame -write_xing 0 /path/mixed.mp3
```

full log =====================================================================

```
liqideMacBook-Pro:pinyin-api work$ ffmpeg -i 
/Users/work/dev/codebase/pinyin/pinyin-api/test/resources/bg_audio2.mp3 
-y -filter_complex [0:0]volume=0.1[output] -map [output] -acodec 
libmp3lame -f mp3 -write_xing 0 /Users/work/dev/codebase/pinyin/pinyin-
api/test/resources/mixed3.mp3
ffmpeg version 3.4.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple LLVM version 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.39.2)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/3.4.1 --enable-
shared --enable-pthreads --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --
enable-avresample --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-
gpl --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libx264 --enable-libxvid --enable-
opencl --enable-videotoolbox --disable-lzma
  libavutil      55. 78.100 / 55. 78.100
  libavcodec     57.107.100 / 57.107.100
  libavformat    57. 83.100 / 57. 83.100
  libavdevice    57. 10.100 / 57. 10.100
  libavfilter     6.107.100 /  6.107.100
  libavresample   3.  7.  0 /  3.  7.  0
  libswscale      4.  8.100 /  4.  8.100
  libswresample   2.  9.100 /  2.  9.100
  libpostproc    54.  7.100 / 54.  7.100
Input #0, mp3, from '/Users/work/dev/codebase/pinyin/pinyin-
api/test/resources/bg_audio2.mp3':
  Metadata:
    title           : 喜洋洋
    album           : 贺岁新年音乐会
    encoder         : Lavf56.4.101
  Duration: 00:02:43.58, start: 0.025057, bitrate: 128 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: mp3, 44100 Hz, stereo, s16p, 128 kb/s
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 (mp3) -> volume
  volume -> Stream #0:0 (libmp3lame)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
Output #0, mp3, to '/Users/work/dev/codebase/pinyin/pinyin-
api/test/resources/mixed3.mp3':
  Metadata:
    TIT2            : 喜洋洋
    TALB            : 贺岁新年音乐会
    TSSE            : Lavf57.83.100
    Stream #0:0: Audio: mp3 (libmp3lame), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc57.107.100 libmp3lame
[libmp3lame @ 0x7fad80001a00] Trying to remove 1152 samples, but the 
queue is empty
size=    2556kB time=00:02:43.57 bitrate= 128.0kbits/s speed=51.7x
video:0kB audio:2556kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global 
headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.003782%
liqideMacBook-Pro:pinyin-api work$
```

=====================================================================

Comment: Share full log.

Comment: No errors reported. How are you checking the output?

Comment: maybe single filter not work in complex filter??

Comment: Nothing like that. How are you checking the output?

Comment: Play with itunes. The volume did not decrease. But when I add a redundant audio (aevalsrc filter) , and amix both，works fine. I'm confused。。。

Comment: `amix` reduces volume in direct proportion to number of inputs.

Comment: @ricklee Your commands work for me.